# How to disable the 'kill' command on Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, kill

I want to disable all kill commands (including root user). I have tried to change permissions, but it still can be executed. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I hate that @xxlali refuses to tell us why this is needed.

Comment: Except for the kernel module that disables the syscall, the user can always write his/her own `kill` executable by calling the c function `kill`.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to disable `kill` on your system?  Do you have processes being terminated by people with root privileges which you don't want being terminated?

Comment: Which kill?

You can send different signals with kill:
 1 HUP      2 INT      3 QUIT     4 ILL      5 TRAP     6 ABRT     7 BUS
 8 FPE      9 KILL    10 USR1    11 SEGV    12 USR2    13 PIPE    14 ALRM
15 TERM    16 STKFLT  17 CHLD    18 CONT    19 STOP    20 TSTP    21 TTIN
22 TTOU    23 URG     24 XCPU    25 XFSZ    26 VTALRM  27 PROF    28 WINCH
29 POLL    30 PWR     31 SYS

Comment: 9 upvotes and 9 downvotes... this deserves a special badge.

Comment: @DigitalChris I have a program. There is another way to stop this program, but some users prefer the stop this program using 'kill -9 %pid%' which causes unwanted results. So, I want to force users to use normal way stop. This is why I want to disable kill command usage. (Please don't hate me :) )

Comment: @xxlali you can e.g. deny solving a problem for a user if you find it has been caused by force killing. A better way is to find out and solve the root UX problem causing them to do this. Maybe the way you provided to stop your program is too inconvenient or nonstandard. Or the program is prone to hanging or something (e.g. if it's GUI and shutdown is slow, you can remove its window so it doesn't nag the user during the process).

Comment: Sounds to me like xxlali is trying to write malware

Comment: If you run a process, only people with the same UID, or with elevated privileges (think `root`) can send signals to your process — see POSIX [`kill()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html).  So, if people using the machine where you run the code make the effort to login as `root` to kill your program, maybe your program isn't behaving well (it is consuming too many of the shared resources on the system).  It's also probable that there are too many people with `root` privilege on the machine.  Should you make 'another way to stop the program' better known?

Comment: Can we kill root progress, if root user is disabled

Answer (score 56, accepted):

"Disabling" `kill` for `root`, even if it was possible, would most likely have unwanted side-effects, like system scripts malfunctioning, and in the worst (but likely) scenario it would prevent your computer from starting up properly (or even *shutting down* properly).

For a user, too, it would cause issues. I have, for example, scripts that I run as an unprivileged user, that checks to see if certain processes are running using `kill -0 $pid`. Those scripts would stop working.

For yourself, you could `alias` the `kill` command to something else, like `echo "kill"`:

```
$ alias kill='echo "kill"'
```

That would prevent `kill` from doing anything useful on the command line at least:

```
$ kill -s HUP $$
kill -s HUP 11985
```

Comment: Disabling `kill` only for interactive use is the only sane answer, so +1.  If you *do* want to use it from an interactive shell with this alias, just run `/bin/kill ...`, or `builtin kill ...` or `command kill` to suppress function/alias lookup.  Bash has keywords to override the default command lookup.  The normal use-case is in wrapper functions, e.g. `cd(){ command cd "$@"; pwd > /tmp/here.$$; }`

Comment: @PeterCordes `\kill` will bypass the alias too.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Oh right, I used to use `\rm` fairly often when I had it aliased to `rm -i` (instead of my current choice of `rm -I`).

Comment: @PeterCordes If you somehow disabled kill for interactive use, the trivial work-around would be to invoke kill via a wrapper script.

Answer (score 70):

Use this kernel module to disable the `kill` system call on `amd64`.
Use at your own risk. Devastating side effects are expected.

```
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int __init init(void) __attribute__((noreturn))
{
     unsigned long long cr0 = read_cr0();
     write_cr0(cr0 & ~(1 << 16));  /* Clear Write Protection (WP) bit */
     *(unsigned char *)sys_kill = 0xc3;  /* opcode for "ret" */
     write_cr0(cr0);

     /* This makes sure that delete_module below won't complain */
     __this_module.refcnt = 1;
     __this_module.state = MODULE_STATE_LIVE;

     asm volatile
     (
          "mov %0, %%rsp\n\t" /* It seems GCC refuses to mess with the stack pointer */
          "jmp sys_delete_module\n\t"  /* call delete_module(name, flags) */
          :: "r"(current->stack + THREAD_SIZE - sizeof(struct pt_regs) - 8), "D"(__this_module.name), "S"(0) :
     );
}

void __exit exit(void)
{
    return;
}
```

Compile it like you would any other module. Then use `insmod` on it.

Comment: It's amazing how you can count on people to hand you multiple guns to shoot yourself in the foot if you ask for it. Including kernel module. :D

Comment: This is my favourite Stack Exchange answer.

Comment: Hopefully at least anyone who knows how to "compile it like you would any other module" knows how much of a bad idea this is.

Comment: Interesting, I guess you modify `%rsp` before tail-calling `sys_delete_module` so the return address is outside the deleted function.  Anyway, always use constraints to ask for your data in the right register, instead of using `mov` instructions.  e.g. use `"D"(__this_module.name)` to ask for it in `%rdi` in the first place.  A `mov` at the start or end of an inline asm block of code is almost always sub-optimal, and better left to the compiler.  I don't think there's a constraint for `%rsp`, though, and I know there aren't constraints for any of `%r8` through `%r15`.

Comment: See also [my collection of how-to-write-good-inline-asm answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm/34522750#34522750), and the [stackoverflow inline-asm tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info).

Comment: Can someone please insert this module in a VM and post a recording of what happens on YouTube?

Comment: Can someone please explain why ET has to be cleared (it seems hard-wired to 1 according to the [AMD64 manual](https://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24593.pdf)) and why the stack has to be prepared in this way? Where does `THREAD_SIZE` come from? In `arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S` it can be seen that a number of registers are pushed to the stack (`sizeof(struct pt_regs)` to be precise), this (and that the return address for `call` (-8)) are ignored. What is following this stack? Kind of disappointing that this answer gets such high upvotes with no explanation...

Comment: @Lekensteyn the stack is set up so after the call to `delete_module` it returns directly to the syscall handler and exits kernel mode. Extension Type was just my sloppiness :(

Comment: @user69874 So, `mov %0, %%rsp` sets the SP to `(current->stack + ...)` (based on the [GCC Extended Asm manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), why this value though?). `"D"(..)` and `"S"(...)` seem to be [constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) to put the values in the rdi and rsi registers, respectively for the first and second argument (name, flags), correct?

Comment: @Lekensteyn `THREAD_SIZE` is the size of the stack. `current->stack + THREAD_SIZE` is the highest address in the stack. After the `struct pt_regs` is constructed on the struct there is a `call *sys_call_table(, %rax, 8)` which pushes the return address immediately after the `pt_regs`. `(current->stack + ...)` is to make sure the `ret` at the end of `delete_module` goes to that address.You are correct in that `rdi` and  `rsi` are the arguments to `delete_module`. Also what do you mean by "ignored" in your previous comment?

Comment: @user69874 Thanks for the clarifications, could you edit these into your post? By "ignored" I mean that the the return address from the `call` instruction is removed from the stack (supposedly). Also, Peter Cordes' comment is more helpful than the current GCC comment, maybe it also worth adding it in?

Comment: @Lekensteyn which `call` do you mean?

Comment: @user69874 The one in `entry_64.S`, `call *sys_call_table(, %rax, 8)`. I could be mistaken though.

Comment: @Lekensteyn No, the `call` instruction in the syscall handler only invokes `sys_init_module` which in turn invokes our `init` function. The return address is in fact used by the system call to later return to the handler. The code above doesn't remove it from the stack, but rather moves the stack pointer right in front of it so `sys_delete_module` will return to the syscall handler.

Answer (score 7):

You *should not* disable it system-wide, because it's used in system scripts (e.g., in `/etc/init.d/functions` in the `initscripts` package).

You can disable it *for the login shell* (and its subshells) by [`alias`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)'ing it to, say, `true`/`false` (or something like `kill_disabled` if you wish to get an error rather than a no-op).

Note that this way is not fool-proof: it will only affect commands executed directly (not those inside scripts). And the user will be able to remove the alias with `unalias`.

---

To do this, run the following command

```
alias kill=kill_disabled
```

or add it to an appropriate [`bash` startup file](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html) to run it at every login.

Now, running `kill` interactively will produce:

```
$ kill 9999
-bash: kill_disabled: command not found
```

---

As I said, the above way is easily subverted. If you need a fool-proof way, the only solution is to run the entire login shell session in a [`chroot`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) environment. It will still only disable the *stock command,* not a direct syscall, however done. The latter cannot be disabled, because it's essential for normal operation (e.g., every <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> sends `SIGINT`, pipes require `SIGPIPE`, and background processes are controlled with more than five different signals). Setting up a chroot environment is an advanced task and it's generally inconvenient if the user needs to access the entire filesystem.

Comment: Well, how can I do that. I am not an advanced linux user.

Comment: @xxlali see the update

Comment: Uh if you run it in a chroot nothing stops you making the kill syscall directly from e.g. another application, which could even be one you compiled and uploaded into the chroot. (Byte by byte if you cared enough). Chroot is nowhere near foolproof. Short of hobbling the system call inside the kernel nothing can stop it completely.

Comment: @Flexo we're talking about disabling the stock application here (the title is "disable the kill _command_"). I never said it would work for a direct syscall. The expression "fool-proof" can be understood to imply that, I must agree.

Comment: @xxlali What are you trying to do? The fact that you are not an advanced user makes it even more likely that disabling `kill` is not what you should actually be doing to solve the problem you're having...

Comment: @DavidYoung I have a program. There is another way to stop this program, but some users prefer the stop this program using 'kill -9 %pid%' which causes unwanted results. So, I want to force users to use normal way stop. This is why I want to disable kill command usage.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the users to be able to use `kill` normally except for when they try to kill your specific program, you can define a `kill` function in the `.bashrc` of the user profile and within this function, check if the user is trying to kill your program. If not, you can call the `kill` utility from within your function itself.

As an example, I wrote a small kill function which will not kill the `sleep` utility but will function as a normal kill utility for any other parameter provided to it.

```
function kill() {
    process=$(ps -p "${@: -1}" | awk 'END{print $(NF)}');
    if [[ $process == "sleep"]]
    then
        echo "Killing $process is not allowed"
    else
        /bin/kill $@
    fi
}
```

Comment: `$process` and `$@` should be `"double quoted"`