# Why doesn’t “sudo rm /bin/kill” delete the kill executable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kill

I tried running `sudo rm /bin/kill` in an Ubuntu VM to delete the `kill` command. Running `which kill` gives no output as if the file doesn’t exist but running `kill` works perfectly ?

Why does the `kill` still work after apparently deleting the executable?

Comment: does it still work after a reboot?

Comment: perhaps `kill` is a built-in for the shell you use.  It is in `bash`.  You might check to see if it is aliased too

Comment: @FrankThomas It was a live ISO in a VM. I will try installing tommorow (10 hours)

Comment: @JakeGould I saw this http://superuser.com/questions/1092083/how-to-disable-kill-command-on-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you issue a `type kill` the response will be:

```
kill is a shell builtin
```

Kill is contained within the bash shell itself.

It is executed directly in the shell directly, without invoking another program.

To know all the commands within the bash shell use `help | less`.